# Télévision à péage

Tags: sens, expressions, étymologie

J'entends de plus en plus souvent parler de **« télévision à péage »**.
Je n'arrive pas à savoir si cela signifie la même chose que **« télévision payante »**.

D'où vient cette expression étrange ? Qu'est-ce qui la justifie ? Qu'apporte *à péage* dans ce contexte par rapport à *payante* (mot bien plus commun, naturel et intuitif selon moi) ?

Surtout que, étymologiquement, *péage* vient de *pes*, *pedis* (le pieds) et non du verbe *payer*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut distinguer d'un côté une expression qui représente la façon de payer (péage) et d'un autre le fait que le « service » ne soit pas gratuit (payante). Les autoroutes sont à péage et payantes, les deux choses ne sont pas nécessairement redondantes. Les autoroutes pourraient être payantes sans avoir pour autant de péages (par exemple avec un relevé des numéros d'immatriculation des usagers). Certains usagers sont exemptés de paiement aux péages...

Pour la télévision (qui est payante en France dans tous les cas au forfait via la redevance), les deux termes semblent synonymes en pratique pour désigner des usages facturés (forfaitaire ou à la consommation).

Comment: +1 Cela me semble plus conforme à l'usage que la réponse sélectionnée.

Answer (score 3):

Une **«télévision à péage»** est le fait de payer pour avoir des programmes. Donc mon fournisseur gère la télévision à péage. Je le paye pour avoir accès a plusieurs canaux.

La **« télévision payante»** est ce qu'on appele en anglais **«pay-per-view»**. Un combat de boxe serait la télévision payante. On paye une fois pour pouvoir l'écouter.

Answer (score 2):

La page Wikipédia *Télévision à péage* renvoie directement sur *Télévision payante*, il n'y a pas donc aucune différence de sens.

*Péage* à pour origine latine 'pedaticum' droit de mettre le pied (ped, pedis), de passer.

Ce terme est utilisé pour les autoroutes : les voitures n'ont pas de pied, mais obtiennent un *droit de passage*.

Les télévisions utilisent des canaux, donc des 'routes' hertziennes ; elles doivent en acheter les droits d'utilisations à l'État.

 Certaines récupèrent leur mise sur les utilisateurs, elles sont dites alors *payantes*.

Le terme *Télévision à péage* est donc le sens juridique du terme dans le sens où elle obtient le droit de faire payer l'utilisateur, et, l'utilisateur est à son tour obligé de s'acquitter d'un péage pour recevoir le flux d'images.

L'utilisateur considère plutôt l'action de payer, et comme le fait remarquer Gilles dans le commentaire la *télévision payante* est celle qui fait payer le consommateur pour la voir.

Comment: L'adjectif *payant* signifie ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/payant) II.A.1) « que l'on doit payer, pour lequel il faut verser une somme d'argent en échange d'une prestation ». Le terme « télévision payante » est parfaitement logique, strictement correct, et usuel. Une « télévision pour consommateurs payants » signifieraient qu'il faut payer pour obtenir des consommateurs ; si tu veux dire que les consommateurs paient, le mot *payant* est un participe présent, pas un adjectif, donc il faut écrire « consommateurs payant ».

Comment: @Gilles Je n'avais que le participe présent en tête, merci de ces remarques qui m'ont permis de corriger la réponse.

Comment: @Gilles Quid du sens II.A.2 ? Cf. *Des auditeurs libres, non autorisés à redoubler leur classe après échec au baccalauréat, mais admis à l'école à titre d'élèves payants*.